Game plugin for Moodle
Lets say I have made quiz type java script games that can have custom input of questions and answers. What would be best path to take to implement these games as a custom Moodle plugin?
I've seen a bunch of tutorials for how to generally make a plugin but not so much for turning quizzes into games. Would plugin skeleton generator work fine for this purpose?

There's a handful of game plugins for Moodle here - https://moodle.org/plugins/browse.php?list=set&id=88 - otherwise you might want to look at Scorm - https://scorm.com/scorm-explained/scorm-resources/scorm-authoring-tools/
